# How to list all cassandra tables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

There are many tables in cassandra database, which contain column titled user_id. The values user_id are referred to user stored in table users. As some users are deleted, I would like to delete orphan records in all tables that contain column titled user_id.

Is there a way to list all tables using CassandraSQLContext or any other built-in method or custom procedure in order to avoid explicitly defining the list of tables?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There are system tables which can provide information about stored keyspaces, tables, columns.

Try run follows commands in cqlsh console:

1. Get keyspaces info

   `SELECT * FROM system.schema_keyspaces ;`
2. Get tables info

   `SELECT columnfamily_name FROM system.schema_columnfamilies WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspace name';`
3. Get table info

   `SELECT column_name, type, validator FROM system.schema_columns WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspace name' AND columnfamily_name = 'table name';`

Since v 5.0.x
[Docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useQuerySystemTable.html)

1. Get keyspaces info

   `SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;`
2. Get tables info

   `SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspace name';`
3. Get table info

   `SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns
   WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspace_name' AND table_name = 'table_name';`

Since v 6.0
[Docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useQuerySystemTable.html)

1. Get keyspaces info

   `SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces`
2. Get tables info

   `SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspace name';`
3. Get table info

   `SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns
   WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspace_name' AND table_name = 'table_name';`

Comment: For my version of cassandra `[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.3 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]` getting keyspace info works with `SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces`

Comment: And for getting tables info `SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspace name'`

Comment: Did it change from `system.schema_keyspaces` to `system_schema.keyspaces` at some point?  Otherwise you may have a typo in the first set of bullet points up there (I would edit it, but I don't have the background info to do so correctly I don't think).

Answer (score 157):

From `cqlsh` execute `describe tables;`

Comment: This is the current and easiest way to list all tables

Comment: For the sake of completeness, run `use my_keyspace;` first.

Comment: Is it possible to alphabetize the output?

Comment: worked for me, make sure to perform `use keyspace_name;` otherwise you will get result for All keyspaces.

Answer (score 24):

```
desc keyspaces;  // list all databases/collections names
use anyKeyspace;  // select any database
desc tables;      // list all tables in collection/ database
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve what you want using datastax core driver and cluster metadata. Here is an example which will list all the tables in your keyspace and columns in each table:

```
 Cluster cluster= Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(clusterIp).build();
    Metadata metadata =cluster.getMetadata();

   Collection<TableMetadata> tablesMetadata= metadata.getKeyspace("mykeyspacename").getTables();
    for(TableMetadata tm:tablesMetadata){
        System.out.println("Table name:"+tm.getName());
        Collection<ColumnMetadata> columnsMetadata=tm.getColumns();            
        for(ColumnMetadata cm:columnsMetadata){
            String columnName=cm.getName();
            System.out.println("Column name:"+columnName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

For DSE. If later release check for system_schema keyspace. 
from

```
cqlsh > desc keyspaces;

spark_system  system_schema  "OpsCenter"  cfs_archive         "HiveMetaStore"
system_auth    cfs          demobeta            dsefs          
dse_security  hypermedia     dse_leases   system_traces       dse_perf       
solr_admin    system         system_distributed  dse_system
```

if you see 'system_schema' then the metadata for tables is in this keyspace.

```
cqlsh>use system_schema;

cqlsh>select keyspace_name,table_name from tables where keyspace_name = 'system';
```

Comment: `system` keyspace isn't DSE-specific - it's a core Cassandra functionality... The schema representation is different between Cassandra versions, so the best way is to either use `cqlsh`'s `DESCRIBE KEYSPACES`, or access via metadata as pointed by @zoran jeremic

Comment: alex, never meant to imply system keyspace is specific to DSE However some are . The schema tables were moved out of the 'system' keyspace so the tables  system keyspace are not in that keyspace any longer .. this is a specific answer for DSE not Open Source Cassandra. Was referring to the metadata for DSE only . desc tables; as posted is really easy way to get a table list . comment was around the metadata for DSE not Open Source . If you are looking for those system tables not in DSE . if trying to generate a table list in your application sometimes can not run a desc but need to run cql...

Comment: system keyspaces are specific for Cassandra. The difference that you describe is difference between Cassandra 2.x & 3.x (See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134185/migration-from-cassandra-2-x-to-3-x-schema-keyspaces-table-is-gone-how-do-you). DSE specific keyspaces usually have the `dse` prefix, like, `dse_security`, `dse_leases`, etc. (although `cfs` & `solr_admin` don't follow this convention). Overall, if you need to access this data programmatically, then it's better to use drivers that support `Metadata` - it's then version agnostic.

Answer (score 4):

To list all the tables (only the table names),

`DESC tables;`

To list all the tables and the schemas (CQL creation statements),

`DESC {$KEYSPACE_NAME}` whereas `{$KEYSPACE_NAME}` is the name of the keyspace.

I am using Apache Cassandra 3.11.4 binary package downloaded from the official site:

```
cql> show version;
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

The Apache Cassandra's CQL reference is here: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL-3.0.html

Answer (score 2):

try running the following query:

```
cqlsh> describe keyspace <keyspace_name>;
```

Comment: cqlsh: describe keyspace <keyspace_name>;

Answer (score 1):

Just connect CQLSH and try below commands

describe tables; or

DESC SCHEMA ;

Also you can 'desc keyspaces;' and 'use keyspace;' where you want to see the tables with 'describe tables;'

Comment: describe schema is not CQL command, but `cqlsh` command...

Comment: @AlexOtt  Yes, I meant after connecting cqlsh.